# Como obter o nome da propriedade a que se refere uma expressão lambda?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma expressão lambda sendo traduzida em uma árvore-de-expressão (expression tree), da seguinte forma:

```
Expression<Func<object>> expr = () => x.NomeDaPropriedade;
```

Como faço para obter o nome da propriedade, que neste caso é `NomeDaPropriedade`, a partir dessa árvore de expressões?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa função tenta recuperar o nome fazendo o cast como MemberExpression, caso não funcionar ele faz pelo UnaryExpression.

```
public static string GetName(Expression<Func<object>> exp)
{
    MemberExpression body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (body == null) {
       UnaryExpression ubody = (UnaryExpression)exp.Body;
       body = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
    }

    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu queria. Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

```
public string AnalizarPropriedade<T>(Expression<T> expr)
{
    var memberExpr = expr.Body as UnaryExpression; // parse da expressao "x.y"
    var operand = memberExpr.Operand as MemberExpression; // parse do operando "y"
    return operand.Member.Name; // parse do nome do operando "y"
}
```

Teste unitario:

```
[Fact]
public void AnaliseDeExpressao_Retorna_NomeDaPropriedade()
{
    //com closure
    string str = "ola";
    Expression<Func<object>> expr = () => str.Length;
    Assert.Equal("Length", AnalizarPropriedade(expr));

    //sem closure
    Expression<Func<string, object>> expr2 = s => s.Length;
    Assert.Equal("Length", AnalizarPropriedade(expr2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar a propriedade pelo corpo do lambda
talvez o metodo abaixo resolva...

```
public String ObterNome<T> (Expression<Func<T, object>> expressao)
{
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression) expressao;

        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression) {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression) lambda.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression) unaryExpression.Operand;
        }
        else {
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression) lambda.Body;
        }

        var member = memberExpression.Member;

        if( member == null ) return null;
        return member.Name;
}
```

o uso é assim

```
string nomePropriedade = ObterNomePropriedade<Pessoa>( x => x.Endereco );
```

Comment: No meu código ele fazia mais coisas, tentei simplificar, mas ta ai

Answer (score 0):

Bom, só para resumir as respostas já dadas, e me baseando nelas, criei dois métodos auxiliares para ajudar nesta tarefa quando necessário, dependendo do formato da lambda utilizada:

```
public String ObterNome<TIn>(Expression<Func<TIn, object>> expression)
{
    return ObterNome(expression as Expression);
}

public String ObterNome<TOut>(Expression<Func<TOut>> expression)
{
    return ObterNome(expression as Expression);
}

private String ObterNome(Expression expression)
{
    var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
    var member = lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
                        ? ((UnaryExpression)lambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression
                        : lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    return member.Member.Name;
}
```

Existe um método para obter o nome, caso se use uma lambda com closure, que aponta para a propriedade, e outra para o caso em que não se tem closure, mas necessita indicar o tipo do parâmetro genérico.